# IIS 7.5 FTP Virtual Directory with Shared Configuration

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5, virtual-directory

I have an Clustered IIS FTP service using the methods outlined here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974603

When adding a new virtual directory, it is not available in the FTP site unless I failover the Clustered Service to a new instance.  The IIS virtual directory administration section doesn't show the virtual directories either.  If I attempt to add them again though, I receive a message that it already exists.  The applicationHost.config file on the Shared Configuration share does show the virtual folders in it, IIS just refuses to re-read it.

I've tried recycling the FTP Server as well as running iisreset from a command prompt.  Neither one work, the only way to have IIS re-read the configuration seems to be to failover to another node.

Does anyone know how to force IIS to re-read the shared configuration?

Update: I just discovered some virtual directories work when hosted on one of the physical servers but do NOT work on another physical server.  In each case, IIS sees the virtual directory fine and I can view the contents on the directory in IIS (on each physical server).  However, attempting to FTP to the server and CD to the virtual directory results in a 550 on the ones where it's not working.

I could use junction points and hide the junction in Windows Explorer to emulate virtual folders, however I'm not sure of any issues that could arise by using that configuration vs an actual virtual folder in IIS.